# spark TextArea not displaying embedded fonts

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, flex-spark

I can't seem to get TextArea to render any embedded fonts in project. I've searched online and have found a couple of instances of this issue but no solutions.

I have a few fonts embedded with my app. Spark Label & the mx:TextArea (switching embedAsCFF to 'false') will display them correctly so I know they're embedded OK. I have the fontFamily value in a binding but I even tried just instantiating a new TextArea then assigning one the the embedded fonts via the fontFamily style and have had no luck. Has anyone experienced this?

```
/* In my CSS file  */
@font-face {
src:url("assets/fonts/UbuntuMono/UbuntuMono-Regular.ttf");
fontFamily: UbuntuMono;
embedAsCFF: true;
}


<!-- In my MXML -->
<s:TextArea fontFamily="UbuntuMono" text="TEST" fontSize="36"/>

<!-- TEST is just rendered as Verdana. Any suggestions? -->
```

Comment: This sounds odd. Have you tried with a different font to be sure to exclude the possibility it might be related to the font? - it might have to do with embedAsCFF being true and the font itself.

Comment: Yes my fonts are rendering just fine for Labels throughout the app. If I change the TextArea tag to Label in the same place, the text renders with the font just fine.

Comment: 1. Is your font only supporting BOLD? 2. can you try with smaller fontsize (12 for ex.) maybe it cannot be displayed because of size.

Comment: Its not a sizing issue. The same TextArea as an MX component displays as it should. I've tried getting this setup on two separate machines using Flex 4.6 SDK with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-created the project and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe guide [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextArea.html), Spark TextArea requires that fonts be embedded differently than the MX version. You can check  more on it [in this discussion](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/635711).

For an alternate solution, you can also try [this](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/15/embedding-fonts-in-flex-gumbo/) .

Comment: The link to the Adobe guide you mentioned is broken. I tried adding fontLookup style value and I'm getting the same result

Comment: According to the discussion, did u try embedding like this  [Embed(mimeType="application/x-font", exportSymbol="MyriadProBold", embedAsCFF="true", fontWeight="bold", source="../../fonts/MyriadPro-Bold.otf", fontName="myMyriadPro")]

Comment: yes I've tried that. I even had a Label control side by side and the font displays fine on the label
`<s:Label fontFamily="myMyriadPro" fontSize="24" text="Yay Myriad!"/>
 <s:TextArea fontFamily="myMyriadPro" fontSize="24"></s:TextArea>`

So I know the font is embedded OK. This is really strange I feel like I'm going crazy because I assume I can't be the only person to run into this.